# Heatmap show previous day in the tooltip

Tags: highcharts, highmaps

I am trying to create a heatmap very similar to that in [this official demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/heatmap-canvas).

However, I am having trouble with the tooltip, which has formatting:

`pointFormat: '{point.x:%e %b, %Y} {point.y}:00: <b>{point.value:,.2f} kWh</b>'`

The problem is that the xAxis shows "30. Jun", but the tooltip shows "29. Jun" (date - 1day)

I am providing a JSFiddle that replicates the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/p5dxt2q2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable UTC.

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    global:{
        useUTC: false
    } 
});
```

Docs: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#global.useUTC